# Going to new page in sveltekit adds new html on top of old one

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a really weird problem that I can't find anything related online, I have a web application built in sveltekit and on one page I have a button that redirects to another page using the `goto` function, but the new page get's added to the bottom of the old one, including the header and shared components it's like the entire page was imported twice in a root component, when I refresh the old one goes away

It's a pretty big website so it's hard to reproduce in a repl

here is the [Link](https://saffron-fr-dev.vercel.app)

Here are the steps to recreate it

- click on order now
- choose pickup (delivery has a radius restriction for address)
- choose any category
- add some items to cart
- once it's in the cart go back to the previous page and select another
  category
- there will be a popup asking you if you are sure since this will
  delete your previous items
- that's when it happens

Any help will be greatly appreciated, If you think any part of the code will be helpful I will post it

Comment: Do you have a source code, because this issue can be caused by a lot of scenarios

Comment: @isaacFinkelstein I checked your website and followed the steps to recreate the issue but it didn't happen for me. Did you figure out the solution? 

BTW, really nice site! But the lack of feedback when I tried to add to cart an incomplete order threw me off and wondered why my cart stayed empty. I think a popup would be really helpful to inform that the order was not put in the cart because it's incomplete.